# Is it possible to rewrite &amp; to &?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is there any way that .htaccess can rewrite all `&amp;` in all URL's to `&` instead?

Comment: Yes, but why do you feel you need to do that in the first place? It sounds like something is double-escaping HTML entities somewhere. It would be better to fix that than to try to cope with the effects.

Comment: Also what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: First, my bad for PHP tag.
Second, Wordpress seems to change all & to &amp;´s instead.

Comment: @FredrikWeiland In the message body?

Comment: In the WYSIWYC when I´m editing the post. If I write a basic link with an & in it, the link works fine but when im pasting a shortcode for a countdowner `[ujicountdown id="Deadline" expire="2012/06/23 00:00" url = "example.com/tavling-avslutad/?kod=123&id=68"]` it turn the ampersand between "123" and "id" into "&amp;" in the url.